# Bluetooth headphones volume too low. Any 3rd party solution to boost?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I alr set the mic input volume in sound in system preferences to max but its still too soft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For wired headphones you have a lot of options. Bluetooth literally is a digital signal, so you have no options other than better receiver to power your headphones. Since you can’t change out Mac amplifier to increase the current or voltage you have two choices For analog:

- Choose lower impedance headphones or more efficient headphones (Sealed or noise cancelling) to make more sound from the same output power.
- Choose a [headphone amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WDXDNM1) to increase the power out or a [100 W  Bluetooth amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W46QV5J) to really make some noise.
- [USB DAC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XBZ38ZJ) can be as cheap as you like - this would be a digital amplifier.

For Bluetooth, the max is just like the dial on the amp, it doesn’t turn any more so once you hit max volume, you have to replace the hardware.

Even if you [turn Bluetooth to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven), max is max.

Comment: So there's no possible digital solution?

Comment: The amplifiers can be digital @JingAnTew

Comment: Then do you have any free digital amplifiers to suggest. I can't seem to find any (probably cause I'm new to this). Thanks for all the help so far though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: There are no free amplifiers. Digital refers to the DAC - it takes a digital output instead of an analog output and sends the pure digital signal to a different amplifier @JingAnTew I added a link to a DAC for less than $20. To be clear, you have to get rid of your Bluetooth headphones, there’s no magic amplifier that will make them louder - you need new gear.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.